# How to format a schedule array with start and end times in a for() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, time

My goal is to have the timer start at the designated times (which it does), but I do not want the dates (Jan 29, 2019) I just want the times, so that I do not have to update the date every single day. Any suggestions on how I can change the for () to work for times and not dates?

I have tried deleting just the date and leaving the time and it will not work.

```
var schedule = [
    ['Jan 29, 2019 20:43:00', 'Jan 29, 2019 21:48:05']
]
<!-- Mainly this part -->
for(var i=0; i<schedule.length; i++){
  var startDate = schedule[i][0];
  var endDate = schedule[i][1];

  // put dates in milliseconds for easy comparisons
  var startMs = Date.parse(startDate);
  var endMs = Date.parse(endDate);
  var currentMs = Date.parse(new Date());

  // if current date is between start and end dates, display clock
   if(endMs > currentMs && currentMs >= startMs ){
      initializeClock('clockdiv', endDate);
      openRequestedPopup();
        myStopFunction();
        setInterval(function(){window.location.reload(5);}, 306000);
        setTimeout(function () { windowObjectReference.close();}, 305000);

}
```

Only display timer with date and time and I just want the timer to display with just the start and end times.

Comment: So you want your schedule array to hold just times and not dates? How are you setting those? I suspect that it's from Date objects, so they will always have date and time. You probably need to alter how you handle them when they come out.

Comment: Ok I have to keep the 2019 in the array but now the timer is counting upwards not down?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I commented, if that is the case something like this should work:

```js
const schedule = [
    ['Jan 29, 2019 20:43:00', 'Jan 29, 2019 21:48:05']
]

for(let i=0; i<schedule.length; i++){
 // pull them straight into Date objects
  const startDate = new Date(schedule[i][0]);
  const endDate = new Date(schedule[i][1]);

 // Make a new Date for setting it for today, then set the hours based off the schedule
 let startTime = new Date();
  startTime.setHours(startDate.getHours(), startDate.getMinutes(), startDate.getSeconds());
  let endTime = new Date();
  endTime.setHours(endDate.getHours(), endDate.getMinutes(), endDate.getSeconds());

 // Easier way to just get the ms and then the same check
 const currentMs = Date.now();
 if(endTime.valueOf() > currentMs && currentMs >= startTime.valueOf() ){
   // Whatever we are doing when it's inside the window
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I still have to keep Jan 29, 2019 in the array andrewf

Comment: Hi Darren, my understanding was you didn't want to have to have Jan 29, 2019 there, just the time? So you can keep the same schedule and check if it's inside the time (not date) window? If so, what I have suggested is to leave the schedule, but then use it for nothing other that the time set in it. If that's not what you want, I think you might need to clarify the question a little.

Comment: Yes andrewf you did accomplish what I needed by running it by checking the time, but the clock timer does not display a countdown from the start time to end time it starts counting up towards something, I am not aware of. Then when it reaches end time it says 00:00 but I do not want it to count up, I want it to display a timer that shows the remaining time till endtime. Thanks

Comment: The endtime has to be set to the current date to work properly

Comment: So where you have initializeClock('clockdiv', endDate); if you use endTime as I have declared it, it will be the time that is in schedule[] but the date if the current day. new Date() is always the current datetime. Without knowing what is in your initializeClock and myStopFunction I can't really help more on how to run your timer

Answer (score 0):

```
var schedule = [
['Jan 30, 2019 10:40:00', 'Jan 30, 2019 12:12:05']
];
for(var i=0; i<schedule.length; i++){
var startDate = schedule[i][0];
var endDate = schedule[i][1];
 // put dates in milliseconds for easy comparisons
var startMs = Date.parse(startDate);
var endMs = Date.parse(endDate);
var currentMs = Date.parse(new Date());

// if current date is between start and end dates, display clock
 if( currentMs >= startMs && currentMs<endMs){ 


  var id =    setInterval(function(){ printTime(); }, 1000);

  function printTime(){
  var time = new Date();
  currentMs = time.getTime();
  var hours = time.getHours();
  var minutes = time.getMinutes();
  var seconds = time.getSeconds();
  document.write(hours + " " + minutes+" " + seconds+" ");


  if(currentMs>=endMs)
    clearInterval(id);  
 }
}
```

}

check this it's may be helpful to you...
  keep learning.....